# insufficient funds for gas * price + value: address on approve usdc on Arbitrum

Tags: web3js, arbitrum

Hi i face error gas insufficient while try to approve usdc on Arbitrum
my wallet have eth around 0.005 ETH
why not enought for L2?

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { Web3 } = require('web3');

// Set up your Web3 provider and wallet information
const web3 = new Web3(process.env.RPC_URL_ARB); // Replace with your Ethereum node URL
const fromAddress = '0xe98bF5be1C897bF130bF077EeE64226d4bc604F8'; // Replace with your wallet address
const privateKey = process.env.privateKey; // Replace with your private key

// Define the ERC-20 token address and the amount you want to approve
const usdcTokenAddress = '0xff970a61a04b1ca14834a43f5de4533ebddb5cc8'; // Replace with your USDC token address
const approvalAmount = '1'; // Replace with the amount you want to approve

// Create a Web3 contract instance for the ERC-20 token
const erc20ABI = require('./protocol/aave/usdce.json');

const usdcContract = new web3.eth.Contract(erc20ABI, usdcTokenAddress);

// Approve the spending by calling the 'approve' function on the ERC-20 token contract
const spenderAddress = process.env.AAVE_POOL_CONTRACT_ARB; // Replace with the address of the contract you want to approve

(async () => {
  // Convert the approval amount to the token's smallest unit (considering decimals)
  const decimals = await usdcContract.methods.decimals().call();
  const multiplier = BigInt(10) ** BigInt(decimals);
  const approvalAmountWei = BigInt(approvalAmount) * multiplier;
  // Build the transaction data
  const data = usdcContract.methods.approve(spenderAddress, approvalAmountWei.toString());

  try {
    // Send the transaction
    const gasLimit = 100000; // Adjust the gas limit if needed
    const gasPrice = '1000000000'; // Adjust the gas price if needed
    const gasPriceWei = web3.utils.toWei('10', 'gwei');
    const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddress);
    const txObject = {
      to: usdcTokenAddress,
      data: data.encodeABI(),
      gas: web3.utils.toHex(gasLimit),
      gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(gasPriceWei),
      nonce: web3.utils.toHex(nonce),
    };

    const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(txObject, privateKey);
    const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);

    console.log('Approval successful. Transaction Hash:', receipt.transactionHash);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during approval:', error);
  }
})();
```

error here

```
Node.js v18.15.0
PS C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\liquidless-auto-repay-client> node .\approve.js
Error during approval: TransactionRevertInstructionError: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM
    at C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\liquidless-auto-repay-client\node_modules\web3-eth\lib\commonjs\utils\get_transaction_error.js:48:21
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\liquidless-auto-repay-client\node_modules\web3-eth\lib\commonjs\utils\get_transaction_error.js:24:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\liquidless-auto-repay-client\node_modules\web3-eth\lib\commonjs\utils\get_transaction_error.js:20:12)
    at getTransactionError (C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\liquidless-auto-repay-client\node_modules\web3-eth\lib\commonjs\utils\get_transaction_error.js:33:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\liquidless-auto-repay-client\node_modules\web3-eth\lib\commonjs\rpc_method_wrappers.js:441:100)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\liquidless-auto-repay-client\node_modules\web3-eth\lib\commonjs\rpc_method_wrappers.js:21:58)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  innerError: undefined,
  reason: 'err: insufficient funds for gas * price + value: address 0xe98bF5be1C897bF130bF077EeE64226d4bc604F8 have 5289780256737969 want 5946492766833840681701790400000 (supplied gas 100000)',
  signature: undefined,
  receipt: undefined,
  data: undefined,
  code: 402
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove your toHex conversion an pass it the string directly. I suspect something wrong is happening there since it want way to much gas.

```
const gasLimit = '100000'; // <- string
const gasPrice = '1000000000'; // <-string
const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddress);
const txObject = {
  to: usdcTokenAddress,
  data: data.encodeABI(),
  gas: gasLimit,
  gasPrice: gasPrice,
  nonce: web3.utils.toHex(nonce)
}
```

Inspect your values

```
console.log("Transaction:",txObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

instead made static use this function for estimate

```
 const estimatedGas = await usdcContract.methods.approve(SPENDER_ADDRESS, AMOUNT_TO_APPROVE).estimateGas({ from: account.address });
```